# promises - unhandled rejection hangs request

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await

I'm developing a backend app in Node.js and I came across with following problem: When developer call promise function like below:

```
mainRouter.get("/xD", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await this.fooService.foo());
});
```

there is possibility that `this.fooService.foo()` function will fail (promise rejection) and the end user will get request timeout.

I want to be sure that developer mistake will not cause UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning (and finally timeout error). The question is **how to configure app to log errors and return status 500 to user when UnhandleRejection occurs.**

What I tried:

```
mainRouter.get("/xD", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(await this.fooService.foo());
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send("error");
    }
});
```

Above code will do the thing but it requiers from developer to write above code in every route, so it's not quite a clean solution.

I also tried to use error middleware:

```
mainRouter.use((err:any, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error");
});
```

but it doesn't catch PromiseRejection

Finally I created middleware which registers function handler for unhandledRecejtion event:

```
mainRouter.use((req, res, next) => {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
        console.log(reason);
        res.status(500).send("Error");
    });
    next();
});
```

I'm not sure how process events works in node.js but I'm afraid that the code above will cause problems for scenario:

1. First request generates unhandled promise rejection
2. The newest request which registered handler last, will return to user status 500.

Comment: "*it requiers from developer to write above code in every route*" - then put an abstraction in `get` itself

Answer (score 0):

Why not just provide a wrapper function that everyone could use

```
async function wrapAsync(res, asyncFn) {
    try {
        res.send(await asyncFn());
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send("error");
    }
}
```

where asyncFn is a function that returns a promise

Then other developers can simply use it this way

```
mainRouter.get("/xD", async (req, res) => await wrapAsync(res, this.fooService.foo));
```

It may also be possible to overwrite `mainRouter.get` and provide an even shorter abstraction

Comment: Are you sure `await` can be used in a non `async` function?